# Bisecting K-mediods

Tags: time-series, clustering, k-means, k-medoids

Is there an algorithm like Bisecting K-mediods and what would its advantages/weaknesses be?

It seems to me that it could be used well in combination of Dynamic Time Warping for clustering time series.